# What if user deletes cookies while navigating your website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Suppose there is page which asks for user's name,age etc. and save it into cookie. Now user is navigating on your website and in between he/she deleted all the cookies and then navigates to the other page which uses these cookies. According to me the next page will get blank values right? How to handle this drawback? I don't want user to fill those details again.

Comment: It depends on how the page uses the cookies, and what was saved in the cookies. The page will not get the cookies - yes - but it cannot be determined if this will result in the page "get[ting] blank values" without more detail of the actual code/process used. For a site with authentication, I would imagine it breaks the flow and asks the user to [re-]authenticate. Also, cookies are *separate* from any values posted back in the page request itself (eg FORM POST action), if that is the concern. My final thought: if someone is deleting cookies while navigating a site, let them live dangerously ..

Comment: The user doesn't have to accept your cookies in the first place. If cookies are required for your website to work and the user's browser doesn't keep them, it just means the user can't use your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: You can use Query String (For Client Side Working)**

Plus Point: very easy alternate of cookies.
Drawback : user can remove query string also.

**Solution 2: You can use Session (For Server Side Working)**

Plus Point : If user delete the cookies ...session value will be saved.
Drawback : Session store value on server so It's little time consuming work.

**Solution 3 :You can save value direct into database.**
Plus Point: all data stored will be saved permanently in your database.in future If user come on your site ...not required again user info.